# Can we get PowerBuilder Pb Data window object using hooking

Tags: powerbuilder

I am testing PowerBuilder application using IAccessible object. But I am not able to get newly added row from PBDataWindow object. Is it possible to get PBDataWindow object using hooking. I can not modify application code  and I don't have there source code also.

Regards,
rajendar

Comment: What language are you using to create the hook? What exactly do you mean by hooking? Have you tried inspecting the window using Spy++ or something similar? What code did you write?

Comment: I am automating pbdw125 control by getting IAccessible object  from AccessibleObjectFromPoint method but it did have all required information. I want automate this control without any limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a datawindow control Accessibility properties using IAccessible but they need to be set in the code (IDE) or in run-time. I suspect this is the case for any Windows application that uses Accessibility unless the language sets default accessibility properties for you when they aren't explicitly provided.

If you don't have access to the source code than you are forced to look at Microsoft Windows 'window class names' to get a handle to objects which will be challenging not to mention that the name of an object might not be consistent across various instances of the application in memory.

For those looking to use Accessibility and have access to the source code, this is how they are set. You can set these for many different object types and columns within a datawindow object.

*Assumption*: Datawindow control is named, "dw_invoice".

**Setting Accessible Properties Dynamically at Runtime**

```
dw_invoice.AccessibleName = 'InvoiceDatawindow"
dw_invoice.AccessibleDescription = "The current invoice"
dw_invoice.AccessibleRole = DefaultRole!
```

**Setting Accessible Properties in Development IDE**

1. Select Datawindow Control
2. Highlight "Other" Tab
3. Enter AccessibleName
4. Enter AccessibleDescription
5. Choose AccessibleRole (see PB help for enumerated list of roles)